# Is there a way to call ruby with require file from php?

Tags: php, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently need execute ruby from php,

`ruby_1.rb` file

```
require 'fileutils'

FileUtils::mkdir_p 'test/abc'
puts 'test'
```

`ruby_2.rb` file

```
puts 'test'
```

php code

```
echo exec("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby test.rb");
```

test.rb is ruby_1 or ruby_2

if running ruby_2 file its ok, but ruby_1 file failed, because of ruby `require`, I've tried other `require` same problem.

Comment: is the ruby 1.2.5 loaded by default ?

Comment: What is the error that you get are getting ?

Comment: @AlokSwain from echo nothing shown, so there must be some problem before puts, btw, I don't know where to find ruby debug log

Comment: you sure you are running the right ruby file ? In the question i see test.rb but it should be ruby_1.rb no ?

Comment: @Alok Swain Ya, I'm sure calling the correct file